# Detect system language change in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, i18next

I am using i18next for localization. I am able to change manually using i18next changelanguage method. But I need to manually change language while change the system language. So is there any package to detect language change in react native

Comment: You can check https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization

Comment: @YogendraGirase I already implemented the localization. Now i need the language change detector event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `react-native-device-info`

```
npm install --save react-native-device-info
```

**getDeviceLocale()**

Gets the device locale.

```
const deviceLocale = DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale();

// iOS: "en"
// Android: "en-US"
// Windows: ?
```

**Update:**

We can `AppState` if the app is in the foreground or background, and notify you when the `state` changes.

If user moved the application to background state, the language has been changed and then open the app again.

While application coming to the foreground state we can check for the language with `DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale()`.

It's the good way to tell that the device's language has been changed or not.

Without moving to background, user will not change the language right?

```
state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!')
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }
```

Comment: I used this. But there is no event happen whenever language change happen. DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale() just give the system language when we manually call it.

Comment: This has changed btw, the functionality is no longer a part of this project and has been split up into a new library 

https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info/issues/833#issuecomment-540001624